# Adobe Animate CC Animation Play/Stop

Tags: jquery, animation, adobe

I have Created an animation using adobe animate CC, I created the animation through timeline and on the last frame of the timeline i have stopped the animation, now in HTML i want to run the animation again on pressing some button placed in HTML, Any thought how I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Flash, add a script in the root timeline:

```
document.myCanvas = this;
```

in HTML:

```
<button onclick="document.myCanvas.play();">PLAY</button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="document.myCanvas.gotoAndPlay(0);">PLAY</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your generated Canvas HTML page, you'll notice that there is an init() function. Inside this function there's a variable called exportRoot which is basically the root or main Timeline.

You can reference this variable without having to create any additional script inside the Animate file itself.

Here's an example of how you can call the play() function in your Body tag:

```
<button onclick="exportRoot.play();">Play</button>
```